# How the mimc bug from circomlib was safely exploited in practice on Tornado Cash?

Tags: contract-development, zero-knowledge, anonymity, pairings, tornado-cash

Several years ago, there was an [unenforced constraint on verification](https://github.com/iden3/circomlib/commit/109cdf40567fce284dca1d535819ce28922653e0#diff-d115e3788e56ac3d62b1f243561d50e5) in the cirmcomlib library : a tool for building projects using ZsNarks. The error allowed to forge cryptographic nullifiers/proofs without having a prior commitment.

Tornado Cash, using `Groth16` was the most well‑known affected case : [the protocol had to be safely exploited](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4f4b7e7ba63a0d836421c4f0447dfedef003dae954b3dddc7d05c412db81fbef) in order to avoid loss of funds.

On [the blog post](https://tornado-cash.medium.com/tornado-cash-got-hacked-by-us-b1e012a3c9a8), there were :

> Later, we will release a step by step guide on how to use this exploit to educate interested security professionals.

4 years later, such blog posts still don’t exist. [And with the ofac sanctions resulting in contributing to any code related to the project banned to ᴜꜱ citizens or peoples living in the ᴜꜱ, is unlikely to ever exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384811).

Neverless, [instead of potential step by step `Zokrates` commands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384811), would it be possible to have this question containing the detailed required computations to generate proofs along nullifiers that verify a root despite not having prior commitments to the root ?